# Flowrouter getQueryParam returns undefined

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I am using this method to get the value of a query parameter:

```
FlowRouter.getQueryParam("s")
```

For a url such as `http://someurl.com/app?s=123`, the above code returns '`123`'. However, if the url is `http://someurl.com/app?s=123#someid` the above code returns '`undefined`'. How to I get the value of `s` in these circumstances?

The url change is instigated by clicking a bootstrap tab. This is important to mention because if I simply type the full url in the browser and hit enter the `getQueryParam()` function returns the correct value.

(Using Flowrouter 2.11.0 with Meteor 1.3)

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to comment, so I write this as an answer. You don't say how you change the url, make sure to call `FlowRouter.setQueryParams()` for it.

Comment: I mentioned that the url is changed by clicking a bootstrap tab.